# When debugging why does visual studio say median is an unassigned variable? -Answered

Tags: c#

So, I am trying to make a console program that analyzes data(well kind of). The problem is when I go to print the median it tells me it is unassigned(well the debugger says this actually). What did I do wrong?
using System;

```
using System;

class midpointFormula
{
    static void Main()
    {
    double min, max, range, median, quartile1, quartile3, internalQuartileRange, IQR15;
    int dataPoints, dataPoints1, count, count1;
    double[] dataSet;
    bool isEven;

    count = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("This program allows you to find several diffrent values from the data");
    Console.Write("Please enter the amount of data points you would like to use: ");

    dataPoints = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    dataPoints1 = dataPoints - 1;

    dataSet = new double[dataPoints];

    #region Enter Data
    while (count < dataPoints)
    {

        count1 = count + 1;

        Console.Write("Please enter the {0} datapoint: ", count1);

        dataSet[count] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        ++count;

    }
    #endregion

    min = dataSet[0];
    max = dataSet[dataSet.Length - 1];
    range = max - min;


    #region Even Check
    if (dataPoints % 2 == 0)
    {
    isEven = true;
    }
    else
    {
    isEven = false;
    }
    #endregion

    if (isEven == true)
    {
        int medianPoint;

        medianPoint = (dataPoints / 2) - 1;

        median = dataSet[medianPoint];


    }
    else


    #region Output
    Console.WriteLine("Minimum is : {0}", min);
    Console.WriteLine("Maximum is : {0}", max);
    Console.WriteLine("Range is   : {0}", range);
    Console.WriteLine("Median is  : {0}", median);
    #endregion

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

}

Note: Yes, I know if there is an uneven amount of datapoints it will not calculate the data points, I am still working on that.

Comment: And in your opinion, is the median variable _always_ initialized?

Comment: Don't think this code would compile at all (even without the issue with the median variable) - I don't see curly braces for the last else block.

Comment: @ James, I am still in the middle of coding, I haven't wrote anything at all for the else yet so it will act like there is nothing there.

Comment: @Tom: `no, it won't!` [act like there's nothing there].  Instead the compiler will take the first statement which follows the `else` keyword and associate it with the else clause; hence very likely introducing a behavior you do not intend or expect.  If you want you can use an empty statement (just a semicolon).  It may also be a good idea to use braces, even for a single or empty statement, so that you don't introduce a logical bug later on by adding more statements and forgetting the braces...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `median` is only assigned a value if `isEven` is true.  If it is not, it will be unitialized.  Since it is *never* acceptable to use a variable that even *might* be unassigned, the compiler prohibits it.

P.S. It's not the *debugger* that is reporting this error, it is the *compiler*.

P.P.S.  What is going on with your **else** statement? -- based on indent it looks like an incomplete thought and an obvious bug.  (`Console.WriteLine("Minimum is : {0}", min);` will only run if `isEven` is false, but the rest of those statements *will* run since they're not enclosed by braces.)

Comment: Thanks, this solved it, and also made me realize that I accidentally put true instead of false in my if statement there. I didn't know this, and will remember that for next time. Thanks